# Does the iPhone backup and restore process include iOS?

Tags: ios, backup, restore

I have become suspicious of whether my iPhone has been compromised (especially with CVE-2022-32893) and decided to do a backup and then restore the backup.

My reasoning was on the assumption that iOS would be completely re-installed and only the user data would be restored.

Is anyone able to confirm if restoring a local, encrypted iPhone backup includes a backup of iOS or if the OS is re-installed?

(Hopefully the question makes sense)

Comment: Make a complete iCloud backup, reset the iPhone, and restore the iCloud backup. iCloud backups certainly do not include iOS.

Answer (score 3):

The backup itself does not contain iOS.

Restoring a backup does not in itself reinstall the operating system. You will need to do that first as a seperate, manual step before restoring a backup.